# Как выслать напоминание пользователю о продлении объявления спустя месяц?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, email, плагин

Всем привет! На сайте установлен [плагин AdRotate](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/adrotate/), в котором каждый зарегистрированный пользователь может разместить свое объявление виде баннера. Хочу сделать так, чтобы по прошествии месяца — на зарегистрированную почту человека, добавившего объявление, приходило напоминание о продлении.
[Установил плагин mailgun](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailgun/), связал его с аккаунтом в сервисе **mailgun**, но пока не понимаю, как добавить функционал, который бы позволил делать отложенную отправку сообщений. Что подскажите?

Comment: сделать скрипт, подключающийся к базе и достающий месячные объявления. Запустить демон с периодичностью раз в день дергать скрипт

Comment: @ArchDemon смысл понятен - а есть хоть пример похожей реализации? подобному ведь нигде не обучают - не понятно от чего даже отталкиваться